# How to remove :checked effect in css for media query

Tags: css, media-queries

For screen > 1000px I want to utilize `:checked` effect(pseudo class). When the input is checked, an adjacent div background color changes to light-blue. When unchecked the background color changes to grey.

In smaller screen (<=1000px), I want to remove everything specified by the `:checked` pseudo class. This means no color change upon check/uncheck.
But I cant make it work.

In other words I want to utilize `:checked` in screen > 1000px and for smaller screen I need behaviour like the previous `:checked` declaration never existed. Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rikotech/r7cmbayp/2/

And some code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            background:rgb(100,100,100);
            /* width: 500px;
            height: 500px; */
            top: 10%;
            bottom: 10%;
            left: 10%;
            right: 10%;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .toggle-label{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .toggle:checked ~ .container {
            background: rgb(100,200,200);;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
            /* I want to remove .toggle:checked ~ .container behavior here
                I dont want checking to change the color or do anything at this screen
             */
             .toggle:checked ~ .container {
                all: unset; /*This doesnt work it just initialize the bacground color*/
            }
        }

        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label class="toggle-label" for="toggle">Hamburger</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `.toggle:not(:checked) ~ .container` inside your @media breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a media query to unset :checked pseudo class in smaller screens, why not write a media query to use :checked pseudo class only in larger screens.

CSS:

```
.container{
  background:rgb(100,100,100);
  /* width: 500px;
  height: 500px; */
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
.toggle-label{
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
  .toggle:checked ~ .container {
    background: rgb(100,200,200);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su2hyLkb/